# when opening socket my program seems to do nothing

Tags: java

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
        boolean isServer=true;
        int port=4000;
        try{
            if(isServer==true){
                new Server(port);
                //starta server
            }
            if(isServer==false){
                new Client(port);
            }}
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("could not start chat");
        }
       
    }
}
class Server{
    ServerSocket server;
    Socket socket;
    Server(int port) throws IOException{
    server = new ServerSocket(port);
    
    socket = server.accept(); 
    System.out.println("got here");
    new ChatParticipant(socket);
    server.close();
    

}}
```

so i have this program which should start a chat between two people but when i first try to start the server i seem to not get to my first print statement and i seem to never start my chatparticipant class either. The problem seem to have to do with the initializing of the socket=Server.accepts() as if i put my print statement before that it prints out. how do i fix this?

Comment: `Socket.accept()` will only return once something has actually connected to your server. So if you only start the server and don't start a client, then it not printing anything is actually the intended behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `server.accept()` blocks your code until a client is connecting to your Server. I bet this wont happen in your actuall test setup.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()
[image: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()]